# How many computations in a CNN

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, convolution

I have not been able to find an answer, so if it is out there, please let me know.

I would like to calculate the amount of time, that a uC needs to give me an Output of an CNN. Therefore, I would like to know, how many computations does a convolution neural network do?

I understand how many parameters it has and how many calculations it does (if every convolution layer has 1 filter).

My CNN has the following design:

```
sample_length = 24
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv1D(8, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(sample_length, 1)))
cnn.add(Conv1D(7, 3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
cnn.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
```

The input layer has 24 neurons and the first convolution layer has 8 filters with a Kernel size of 3. So, I need (24 - 3 + 1) dot products of  size 3 and (24 - 3 + 1) additions for the bias for one filter. That gives me 176 dot products with size 3 and 22 additions of 2 numbers. The output now has shape (22, 8).

Let us assume, the next layer has just 1 filter with Kernel size of 3. How does the filter slide over this layer to get an output size of (20,1)? Does it have to compute a dot product for the first 3 neurons of each "dimension" and then add them together?